# Having trouble linking Cassandra and Thrift sources in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cassandra, thrift

I am using Cassandra (0.7.2) and Thrift (0.7) with eclipse 3.4 and having trouble getting the source files linked in. I have built both Thrift and Cassandra using ant, after building Cassandra there is a sources directory under build/lib which contains source .jars. Unfortunately even after linking these into eclipse, I still can not see the source for anything. To add sources I am going to build path->sources tab->link source (here I select the source folder containing the source jars). I have also tried ctrl-clicking on classes, which complain that no attached source could be found, and I try to specify the source path via the browse button provided. Still no luck

I am a bit new to eclipse, so it certainly could be user error on my part. Any pointers or tips?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always set up the source like this: `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries tab`, expand the Jar, select 'Source attachment', click 'Edit', and select the source Jar or Zip file for the Jar.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a 'generate-eclipse-files' ant target actively maintained. If that does not work out of the box for you, then it is a candidate for an issue.